# How to find grid badge when debugging gird layout in google chrome browser developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, css-grid, grid-layout

I'm learning to debug grid layout. Here is the article about it: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/grid
[Here what says Chrome DevTools guide.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNimd.png)
The issues comes on the very first stage - I cannot find grid badge on my Elements panel in DevTools.
I've already checked on Windows and MacOS, I seems like it's not connected to OS.
Does anybody know how to turn it on?
Maybe I need to change my browser settings?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and fixed it by chance by doing this:

1. Open DevTools settings
2. On **Preferences** go to the **Elements** section
3. I had all selected, except *Show rulers* and *Show agent shadow DOM* so I selected them too.
4. It worked! The Grid label started to appear on grid elements and could on **Elements**

The thing is that I deselected again *Show rulers* and *Show agent shadow DOM* to discard which of them was the one that activated the Grid label but then the Grid label didn't disappear. That's why I said I fixed it by chance.